# Color of comments affects frame color in listings

Tags: listings, code, comments

I use listings package with single frame around it, when i place long comments in my code color of comments affects frame color. Frame around lines with comments are green. I want frame to be black, always.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C++,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
        frame=single, 
        breaklines=true,
}


\begin{lstlisting}
void foo()
{
  for (int i=0 ; i<VALUES_SIZE ; i++)
  {
    int x=i*2;//some very long comments about actual code in this line
    int y=i*2;//some really very very very long comments about actual code in this line spreading over two or three long lines
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. I searched for listings and color, and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make `rulecolor` black.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{listings}
\begin{document}
\lstset{language=C++,
        basicstyle=\ttfamily,
        keywordstyle=\color{blue}\ttfamily,
        commentstyle=\color{green}\ttfamily,
        frame=single,
        rulecolor=\color{black},    %%% <--- here
        breaklines=true,
}


\begin{lstlisting}
void foo()
{
  for (int i=0 ; i<VALUES_SIZE ; i++)
  {
    int x=i*2;//some very long comments about actual code in this line
    int y=i*2;//some really very very very long comments about actual code in this line spreading over two or three long lines
  }
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{document}
```

[image]